# Unable to get date in proper format when days are less than 12 FROM EXCEL in C#

Tags: c#, excel, date, ms-office

I am new to c# . When i am trying to import excel sheet using the following code :

```
  try
                        {

                            DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(w.Cells[i, index[j]].value2);
                            string str = date.ToString("d-M-yyyy");
                            dRow[j] = Convert.ToDateTime(str, ci);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                String ss1 = (String)w.Cells[i, index[j]].value2;
                                if (ss1 == null || ss1.Equals("NIL") || ss1.Equals("."))
                                {
                                    dRow[j] = DBNull.Value;
                                }
                                else if (ss1 != null)
                                {
                                    DateTime dat = Convert.ToDateTime(ss1);
                                    ss1 = dat.ToString(ci.NumberFormat);
                                    dRow[j] = Convert.ToDateTime(ss1,null);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dRow[j] = DBNull.Value;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex1)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    String ss2 = (String)w.Cells[i, index[j]].value2;
                                    if (ss2 != null)
                                    {
                                        String ss2_t = ss2.Trim();
                                        DateTime da = DateTime.ParseExact(ss2_t, "d-M-yyyy", null);
                                        dRow[j] = da;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        dRow[j] = DBNull.Value;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex2)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        String ss3 = (String)w.Cells[i, index[j]].value2;
                                        if (ss3 != null)
                                        {
                                            String ss3_t = ss3.Trim();
                                            DateTime da1 = DateTime.ParseExact(ss3, "d-M-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                            dRow[j] = da1;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            dRow[j] = DBNull.Value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception)
                                    {
                                        dRow[j] = DBNull.Value;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Everything works fine untill date has day value less than 12. For example if DATE is 23-07-2013 it works fine . but if DATE is 7-5-2013 then  DateTime.FromOADate() convert it into 5-July-2013 . I am totally stuck. Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the difficulty is with your `str` variable then use this format:

```
string str = date.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

**Update**

The argument passed to `DateTime.FromOADate()` is a double which is obviously not format sensitive. So I'm not exactly sure why you'd need to convert it to a string and then back to a date. Is it possible that `dRow[j] = date` is all you need?

If the returned valued of `FromOADate()` is incorrect then you need to return to your source data, ie Excel. You would need to adjust the format settings there or, if that data was imported, run a small VBA macro to convert the values yourself.

I'm not sure where in the code you are seeing the "d-M-yyyy" v. "M-d-yyy" difference. If you are looking at your `dRow[j]` variable then this will abide by your defined `CultureInfo`, presumably the `ci` variable.

Below is some code that shows three ways of managing date string conversions, the first two manipulate the `CultureInfo`, the third is pure manual string parsing.

Have a play to see if any of these suit your needs, but I still return to my original question of "do you need to go 'date - string - date' at all"?

```
DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(42491);
string str = date.ToString("d-M-yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(str);

//CultureInfos
CultureInfo ciGB = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false);
CultureInfo ciUS = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);

//ToDateTime version
DateTime dateGB = Convert.ToDateTime(str, ciGB);
DateTime dateUS = Convert.ToDateTime(str, ciUS);
Console.WriteLine("ToDateTime: GB = {0}, US = {1}", dateGB, dateUS);

//ParseExact version
DateTime parsedGB = DateTime.ParseExact(str,"d-M-yyyy", ciGB);
DateTime parsedUS = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M-d-yyyy", ciUS);
Console.WriteLine("ParseExact: GB = {0}, US = {1}", parsedGB, parsedUS);

//Manual parsing
var parts = str.Split('-');
int item1 = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int item2 = int.Parse(parts[1]);
int item3 = int.Parse(parts[2]);
DateTime manualGB = new DateTime(item3, item2, item1);
DateTime manualUS = new DateTime(item3, item1, item2);
Console.WriteLine("Manual: GB = {0}, US = {1}", manualGB, manualUS);
```

Comment: i already tried this.... problem is with the Datetime.FormOADate() . This function returning wrong date to my variable date.

Comment: @RajSinghRathod, if `FromOADate` is your issue then the data within Excel is in the wrong date format because a date `Value2` returns a double (Long in VBA) which is not format sensitive. Try setting the format manually in Excel to see if you get better results. If the data in Excel is good, then I've added a few points to my answer that may help you.